# Finding data on how users interact with web GIS?

Tags: cache, web-gis

I’m developing a geospatial data viewer that connects to various services (WMS, WMTS). I have a server that clients connect to. When a client makes a request, I cache it on the server. However, I would like to start prefetching likely to be requested by the client tiles. In researching this I’ve come across many prefetching algorithms in research papers: Retrospective Adaptive Prefetch is a user driven algorithm that applies heuristics to recent user actions to determine what tiles need to be prefetched. Tile Prefetching Based on Previous k Movements prefetches tiles based on recent user movement. Distributed Caching System Based on Spatiotemporal applies a heuristic based on when user movements occurred.

The issue I’m running into is these all these algorithms require user interaction data to get started.

Is there a source that has user interaction data with GIS sources?

I know places like OpenStreetMap have data that shows the total amount each tile was accessed in a day, but they don’t share the user trace of accessing those tiles.

I’m working in Python and it’s possible I’ve missed some great package that does geospatial prefetching tile prediction. I seek any easy solutions like this.

Comment: Probably for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ (analytics)

Comment: @Mapperz I'm not sure that this fits in at webmasters. The first paragraph was the explanation of why I needed the data. I'm don't think webmasters is on topic for asking: "If a user zooms in on Africa where do they tend to zoom in next." That's the data I'm looking for.

Comment: I doubt you can rely on other services stats. The user behavior is dependent on the data your are showing (ex: users of an inter-city routing machine will follow highways between cities, while users of a touristic website will pan in circle around a center place)

Comment: It might be easier to launch your service without a "smart" pre-fetch, analyze the data then implement an optimized pre-fetching mechanism

Comment: @JGH The research I've been reading suggests that trends across different data types exist, but it looks like no public data set exists to prove this. I guess for now I'll just prefetch very hot tiles around the clients location till I build up log data.